# get all sub-groups of hierchical list in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables like these:

category table

```
id       category_title      category_parent
----     --------------      ---------------
 1          sport                   0
 2        electronic                0
 3         football                 1
 4        volleyball                1
 5         laptop                   2
 6        television                2
 7        basketball                1
```

product table

```
 id       product_name       product_category(referenced to id column from category table)
----     --------------      ---------------
 1         product1                 3
 2         product2                 3
 3         product3                 4
 4         product4                 4
 5         product5                 5
 6         product6                 6
 7         product7                 7
```

I want to get all products in a main category (for example I want to get all products from product table that their category is sub-category of sport). what is the right SQL query?
(for example I want to get these products: product1, product2, product3, product4, product7 that are in football, volleyball, basketball categories. These categories are sub category of sport. So I want to get all products with sport category!)

Comment: Please include what is your desire result with this data sample so we get a better idea what query you need. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: I want a SQL query that returns all products which have different categories. But these categories have same category_parent.

Comment: I know, but I cant translate those words in a query result. So if you create a similar table as the one you already have will help a lot.